# How a custom form control can get a validation value?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am working on a custom form control, that is, a component that implements the [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface in order to be used along with the Angular forms API.

There is some validation logic for that component. For example, `Validators.max` with its value is in use. My intention is if the validation fails the component would show an error message with the right value.

However, to show this message the component needs to know the max value. So, my question is how can I pass it? Is `@Input()` the only option or the forms API provides another, more clear, way for this sort of situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the associated form control into your component constructor, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss'],
  providers: [ ... ]
})
export class MyComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  // . . .

  get control(): FormControl {
    return this.ngControl?.control as FormControl;
  }

  constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
  }
}
```

Then, in your template, you can use it like this:

```
<span *ngIf="control.hasError('max')">
    Max {{ control.getError('max').max }} allowed
</span>
```